The Issuer https://a.com/auth/realms/arealm provided in the configuration metadata did not match the requested issuer http://a.com/auth/realms/arealm
I'm using Spring Security together with Keycloak and have the following configuration in my properties:
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri = http://a.com/auth/realms/arealm

Which the protocol part is http
My keycloak publicly resides at https://a.com/auth/realms/arealm, where the protocol part is https
My keycloak is started using the following options:
    command:
      - start
      - --optimized
      - --http-enabled=true
      - --proxy-headers
      - forwarded
      - --hostname
      - https://a.com/auth/
      - --hostname-backchannel-dynamic=true

In my setup, keycloak and my app is on the same local network and https is terminated by a load balancer in front of both keycloak and my app. If I call the following url from my app I can successfully get a response:
curl http://a.com/auth/realms/arealm/.well-known/openid-configuration

So I'm guessing backchannel config works and network related parts are ok.
But Spring Security is still complaining and giving me the error :

The Issuer https://a.com/auth/realms/arealm provided in the configuration metadata did not match the requested issuer http://a.com/auth/realms/arealm

I don't want to change the url in Spring properties to https because then I'd have to somehow force my app to go over internet to reach keycloak, so that request goes through load balancer and https gets terminated. I did that by explicitly adding a line to /etc/hosts with my public IP address but it's an ugly solution, but it works:
1.2.3.4 a.com
How can I stop Spring Security complaining about mismatched issuer uri?


How can I stop Spring Security complaining about mismatched issuer uri?

You can't without disabling OIDC discovery and iss claim validation: leave the issuer-uri empty in application properties, providing all other provider properties.
The OpenID spec requires that the Issuer Identifier matches exactly in the discovery endpoint payload and token claims. That includes the scheme and an optional trailing slash.

then I should  find a way to somehow force my app to go over internet and not local network to reach Keycloak

Not necessarily. Having something on the local network resolving the issuer to a local address is just fine (the hosts file like you did, a service discovery, or whatever).

I modified the dns entry in route53 which used to point a.com directly to the internal IP of the instance to instead point to the aws load balancer, so even local traffic goes through the load balancer and I can use https issuer uri. Not sure if it's the best way but seems to be working now. Thanks!

@ch4mp What is a real world use case for hostname-backchannel-dynamic=true? I thought it is for private communication between client and Keycloak. But OP's use case is not included. How can some one use this feature?

I'm not sure about what you mean by "OP's use case". https://www.keycloak.org/server/hostname#_utilizing_an_internal_url_for_communication_among_clients with this, the OP should be reachable using different Issuer Identifiers (everything should change depending on the hostname used in requests: OIDC discovery URI, issuer in OpenID conf, and iss claim in tokens. I don't use that and always point all parties to the public reverse proxy, using the exact same Issuer Identifier everywhere.

If you're using only confidential clients, all should be on your local network. It's possible for such Relying Parties to use only the private network to talk to the OP (Keycloak). You can even set a firewall rule to forbid access to the token endpoint from the internet. The only endpoints that need to be publicly available are the authorization endpoint and what serves the login UI. But this firewall can be applied in front of the proxy (clients still using the public hostname and going through the proxy).
